# CoreLocation stops monitoring after few minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, ibeacon

Device (iPhone 4s, iOS 8.4) situated in Region with 3 iBeacon devices. After 4-9 minutes of laying CoreLocation generate ExitRegion. After few minutes generate ExitRegion and continues working. All this time application in the foreground and connected to x-code.

UPD: It does not reproduce in (iOS>9 and iPhones 5). 
On my device, it reproduces in 1 minute if I browser in facebook

Comment: Can you show us the code you wrote ?

Comment: Olivier, I can add code, but it hasn't sense. It looks like some power consumption behavior. I use only methods from CoreLocation. Suddenly it stops getting frames, after few minutes, starts again.

Comment: Do you have a second iOS device to test to see if it is a beacon or device-specific issue?

Comment: It makes sense to show the code. Since the behavior of your program is not the one expected when using CoreLocation (at least I don't think so), without code, we can't really help you. But as @davidgyoung said, you should try with another device if you have one

Comment: Another thought is to test with an off the shelf beacon application like Locate to see if you see the same problem.  This might help eliminate a coding issue. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8

Comment: I will try in another device.

Comment: It does not reproduce in (iOS>9 and iPhones 5). Now I am watching it only on my iPhone. Looking for the same device.

Comment: Is your app in background ?

Comment: Zil, no. Not in the background. In the foreground and connected to x-code